# VSCode command to go up and down in Context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've assigned `, ,` to open context menu (that we usually open by mouse right click) using the following:

```
{ "key": ", ,",               "command": "editor.action.showContextMenu"},
```

Now I'd like to be able to navigate this opened list with `ctrl+j` and `ctrl+k`.

I don't know which command and condition should I use for this?